# Reload .bashrc by GNOME, not by terminal

Tags: ubuntu, path, bashrc

I've changed `$PATH` in `.bashrc` and would like the Ubuntu command launcher (opened by `Alt+F2`) to search for commands in the updated `$PATH`. Is it possible to do without restarting the GUI session?

Comment: Could you please try to add your new `$PATH` to your `.profile` file? Would it work then?

Comment: Nope, it does not. Seems like ~/.profile is not rerun when Alt+F2 is pressed.